# "cannot call WebBrowser methods until it is in the visual tree" even when calling in the Loaded event handler

Tags: windows-phone-7

In my Windows Phone application, I receive the error:

"You cannot call WebBrowser methods until it is in the visual tree" 
But I am calling web browsers method in the Loaded event handler.

Moreover, the same code works perfectly fine in another application, the only difference being that the other application has an AdControl in it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You're going to have to add some code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Page.Loaded or webBrowser.Loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The loaded event may be being called before it's container has been loaded. Make sure that everything has loaded before trying to navigate.